# How to create a Mono triggered by completion of a flux

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactor

I have a class that populates a Map from a Flux source. I want to able to `updateTheData()` on the fly, but I want `getTheData()` to be able to return a Mono that resolves to current or pending data.

Basically if theData != null and no in progress flux, return Mono.just(theData)
Otherwise return mono that will eventually emit theData.

Edit: This is the best I can do so far

```
    class SomeClass {
        private Mono<Map<String, Data>> theData;
        private final SomeFluxService someFluxService = new SomeFluxService();

        public SomeClass() {
            updateTheData();
        }

        public void updateTheData() {
            someFluxService.get()
                .collectMap(Data::getId, Function.identity())
                .subscribe(d -> this.theData = Mono.just(d));
        }

        public Mono<Map<String, Data>> getTheData() {
            return this.theData;
        }
    }
```

But there is still the problem of before `updateTheData()` completes for the first time, `getTheData()` will return null

Help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But there is still the problem of before `updateTheData()` completes for the first time, `getTheData()` will return null

This is because you're using a consumer in your subscribe method to update a `Mono` only when data is emitted. This is a bit of an odd approach, it would be better to simply `cache()` the `Mono` and then assign it to your field straight away:

```
public void updateTheData() {
    theData = someFluxService.get()
            .collectMap(Data::getId, Function.identity())
            .cache();
}
```

Taking that thinking a step further, if your requirement is to update the data every `x` seconds rather than inherently on demand, you can just pass that into the cache function and do away with the separate method entirely:

```
public NewClass() {
    theData = someFluxService.get()
            .collectMap(Data::getId, Function.identity())
            .cache(Duration.ofMinutes(5));
}

public Mono<Map<String, Data>> getTheData() {
    return theData;
}
```

Comment: This looks much better thanks! There is one minor difference though in that the original one will keep returning the current data until there is successfully new data. But I think I can work that into you solution by just keeping 2 monos and swapping...

Comment: @Brian It's different, but your brief was to return the cached data only if there's available cached data and the flux is *not in progress*, which is what this does :-)